# How Do I Select A Sub-Field For A User?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get information about users from Microsoft Graph Explorer. The default query gives me way too much info per user https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users

Therefore, I am getting a subset of data using `$select` https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?&$select=id,displayName,identities which looks like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users(id,displayName,identities)",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "06609x07-2b89-5l92-8egg-5666a36uu26w",
            "displayName": "Joe",
            "identities": [
                {
                    "signInType": "emailAddress",
                    "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "issuerAssignedId": "joe.bloggs@contoso.com"
                },
                {
                    "signInType": "userPrincipalName",
                    "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "issuerAssignedId": "06609x07-2b89-5l92-8egg-5666a36uu26w@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to modify the select so that it doesn't return the whole `identities` block but just returns the `issuerAssignedId` field instead (ideally just the first one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems **impossible** to return only `issuerAssignedId` field with $select.

[That](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#select-parameter) describes the operation of $select. There is no mention of $select in the properties.

> Use the `$select` query parameter to return a set of properties that are
> different than the default set for an individual resource or a
> collection of resources. With `$select`, you can specify a subset or a
> superset of the default properties.

On the other hand, the `issuerAssignedId` just supports `$filter`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/objectidentity?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: Are you saying that with a combination of the two I could get id, displayName and issuerAssignedId?

Comment: No, I mean it is impossible, $select doesn't support nested property.